# CloudFormation stack gives "API: s3:GetObject Access Denied"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm having issues deploying CF-stack when used in combination with a S3 bucket.
The S3 bucket contains a swagger definition that API Gateway needs to access.

My S3 bucket has a bucket policy that contains an IP-filter, along these lines:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IpFilter",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "Service": [
                    "lambda.amazonaws.com",
                    "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-code-dev/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1.2.3.4/32",
                        "5.6.7.8/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The intent is to deny access to this S3-bucket for anyone not coming from the specified IP addresses or for the specified services.

When deploying my stack I'm hitting an error when deploying the AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi resource with Status Reason "API: s3:GetObject Access Denied".

This is obviously tied to the bucket policy, because if I remove the policy the issue disappears. Any ideas as to what is missing in the policy?

Comment: unsure, but maybe you have to add cloudformation as a principal as well?

Comment: I have actually tried that as well, it doesn't help

Comment: Where have you defined the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resource? Perhaps you can ensure that the s3 bucket has been created completely first, by specifying `DependsOn: "myS3Bucket"`